# Exceptions not handled in JPA

Tags: web-services, jpa, transactions

We developed the stateless Web-service implementation. We used JPA as ORM layer to do the database operations. In service methods, we used the Entity Manager to persist the entity.
        while persisting the same record into the table, we are not able to handle those exception "Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (TIGOSUSCRIPTIONES.SYS_C0020549) violated" exception in Service method.
     It is directly throwing the following exception in client result.

```
      Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Transaction rolled back
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
        at $Proxy30.registerSaleOutcome(Unknown Source)

      How can I handle this exception? Following is the code we used in service method business logic.


@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void recycleOperation(Recycle recycle) throws RecycleFault_Exception{
  try {
    em.persist(recycle);
  } catch(Exception e){
    // not coming to this block
    log.error("Exception in Data Insertion:"+e.getMessage());
    RecycleFault fault = new RecycleFault();
    fault.setErrorCode("101");
    fault.setMessage("Record is already Existed");
    RecycleFault_Exception faultExp = 
        new RecycleFault_Exception("RecycleFault Exception", fault);
    throw faultExp;
  }
}
```

Could you help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
```

This causes the method to be wrapped in a JTA transaction, when the transaction fails, the exception will be thrown to the caller.  You will either need to handle this in the caller, or through an exception handler, or switch the method to use a bean managed transaction.

You could also call flush() in JPA, that will trigger the constraint exception, and allow you to handle it.  But the JTA transaction will still fail.